# Subversion: Configure svn access through http protocol

Tags: svn, http, configuration, ubuntu

I got a ubuntu server edition with subversion, apache2, openssh and need repositories for svn connection with/without any protocol (ssh, file:, http, https, etc).
I configured a repository directory

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repos/project
```

Made an import

```
svn import /path/to/import/directory svn+ssh://user@ipaddress/path/to/repos/projectFolder
```

Configured the apache2 and restarted the server

```
/etc/subversion/mod-avaliable/dva_svn.conf

<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/svn 
AuthType Basic
AuthName ”Your repository name”
AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Already gave permition to the www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/repos
```

However when trying to access the repository through browser I got 403 Forbidden access.
How should I proceed?

Thanks for the attention

Comment: is /path/to/repos a subdir under /home/svn ? How did you add users to /etc/subversion/passwd ? and does the apache error log contain anything of interest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is enabled in your configuration:

> Require valid-user

In order to access your repository you must add a user:

```
htpasswd -m -c /etc/subversion/passwd PLS
```

Comment: I did that. I forgot to write. My mistake. I solved the problem configuring the <Location> </Location> tag in the dav_svn.conf by using SVNPath instead of SVNParentPath since I had only one project.

Comment: Hi, PLS. If the question has been answer satisfactorily can you give someone (you or zellus) credit?